# How to get the token of words which matches in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

- I need list of values of words which matches. if my search string is `abc` which is theere in my name of document my expected out is just list of values [`abcdef`, `abcdefgh`, .....]

myd is below

```
[
{'id':1,  'name': 'christiano ronaldo', 'description': 'portugal'},
{'id':2,  'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'argentina'},
{'id':3,  'name': 'Lionel Jr', 'description': 'brazil'}
]
```

DSL query is below

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "name": {
        "query": "lio",
        "slop": 3,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My output is below

```
{'took': 2,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 2, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 0.4700036,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '2',
    '_score': 0.4700036,
    '_source': {'id': 2, 'name': 'lionel messi', 'description': 'argentina'}},
   {'_index': 'players',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '3',
    '_score': 0.4700036,
    '_source': {'id': 3, 'name': 'Lionel Jr', 'description': 'brazil'}}]}}
```

- is there any way to extract the token word which matches

Like my expected out is only is just `lionel` only as `lio` matches the name which is `lionel` and `Lionel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no direct way to get only the text's matched tokens in the search result.

However, one method is to use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) to get the matching terms in the text.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "name": {
                "query": "lio",
                "slop": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "name": {}
        }
    }
}
```

You can parse the search result response and retrieve the highlighted terms later on the application side.